# Highcharts - Multiple master charts in master detail charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using - http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail/sand-signika/

I am trying to have two master charts (bottom one) instead of one. So that scrolling in synchronized for both of them ,but different data is displayed.

Can someone please suggest. Or if someone has tried something similar before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try to add extra chart (as details at the bottom, which are additional chart) and set there different data.